# Appending Rows into an SQLite Database Where Primary Key May Already Exist

Tags: sql, database, merge, sqlite

I’m trying to merge a few pairs of SQLite3 databases that have the same tables (and schemas). Some of the tables are pretty simple and just have rows of plain data, but some of the tables have primary keys. Some of the keys are unique like a URL (eg `url LONGVARCHAR PRIMARY KEY`), and some of them are just simple integer indexes, but NOT set to auto-increment (eg `id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`).

I’ve found several topics on merging databases (and I had already manually merged one pair of non-primary-key databases without effort), but am concerned about the ones with keys which may already exist in both.

My question is what happens if a row is inserted to a database where a row with the same key already exists? It should overwrite the row that has that key right? I was hoping that it would append them to the table and update the key, but that only works if the key has a numeric component that is set to auto-increment correct?

Can anyone confirm my suppositions—and if possible, offer a suggestion on the easiest way to append such rows?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You should have no problems if you set the primary key in the destination table to auto increment.

Therefore, when you do you bulk insert command or whatever you are using to insert values into your new table, you simply do not supply input for your primary key field and there will NEVER be a duplicate.

Columns:

ID  Name

Just don't provide ID field, ie/

INSERT INTO tableName ("Synetech")

The insert would just add this with the next available ID index in the table.

Good Luck!

Comment: And then I can dump the resulting database to an SQL file which should have the keys numerically incremented, and finally remove the auto-increment from the `CREATE TABLE` command and create a database from that. I’ll give that a shot. It sounds like it would work and be less cumbersome than what I currently did (using RegEx in Notepad2 to strip out the ints, and then use a PHP script I wrote to insert them back with incrementing values).

Answer (score 0):

If you try to INSERT a duplicate primary key, it will give you an error and not allow the insert. SQLite also supports the 'REPLACE INTO' syntax, which will update on a duplicate primary key.

If you want to append on duplicates, you will have to check whether a field with that key already exists, and if so then change the key to some new value. The correct way to do this likely depends on your application. For integer keys you could just take the max+1, but for the url keys it's not clear what the correct behavior should be.

Comment: Right; inserting when the key exists fails, but updating overwrites the row—why isn’t there an APPEND command? `:-(` For URL keys, it’s mostly just a matter of updating the row with the same row from the most recent database. Is there a way to automate the max+1 method? I’m using the SQLite3 commandline program; is there another tool that would make that task easier?

Comment: There *is* an APPEND statement; we call it INSERT. Keys are your friend.

Comment: @CatCall, he doesnt mean APPEND to table... The OP clearly describes his use of INSERT.